# spring view template skinning

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, themes, skinning

How can I implement a css based template skin for spring MVC app. Also, is it possible to change the template path for spring MVC file at runtime to load completely different theme based on user selection or url called?

Comment: Have you done an internet search on this? You need to provide evidence of research when asking a question (see the FAQ). Here's a clue to the templating: Sitemesh & Tiles.

Comment: If I had found an answer from internet search then why would I be asking the question on stackoverflow ?

Comment: If my question is too open ended then how come @madhead was able to reply accurately even before you posted the first comment?
 Secondly I am not considering different type of app here. My question is related to a specific framework and specific configuration in the given framework. Your comment is absurd in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Spring](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-themes-tutorial-example/) [Themes](http://www.devmanuals.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring3/mvc/Spring3-MVC-Themes.html). Also, there are other options:

- You may change class of `<body>`, for example, and have different themes [as it is done in Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/themes.html).
- You may [load stylesheets as `alternate`](http://css-tricks.com/examples/AlternateStyleSheets/) and switch them with JS.